# Alternative to logarithmic mesh spacing

Tags: audio, graphics, signal-processing

I'm currently trying to render an audio frequency waterfall plot.
Audio Spectrum Analyzers usually have a logarithmic X-Axis, which is what I want to achieve as well. So in my setup I calculate the x component of the mesh like this:

```c
// This is just pseudo-code

float max_frequency = sample_rate / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < mesh_width; i++) {
    float frequency = i / (mesh_width - 1) * max_frequency;
    float x = log(frequency + 1) / log(max_frequency + 1);

    mesh[x_index] = x;
}
```

However, this leads to extreme z-fighting in the high frequencies. Presumably because the vertices are so dense.

One idea I had to combat this is to have a regular mesh with linear spacing and map the FFT data to the respective vertices. I'm not exactly sure how to implement this, though. Is this even a reasonable approach? If not, what other possibilities exist?

Thank you in advance for any answers! :)

– schroffl

Comment: I think the plot should be like a bin for each x coordinate so you should average all the frequencies that points to it ... as you obviously do not do that then the used frequencies are jumping between neighboring frequencies causing the fighting... Sounds like Its not z fighting but aliasing instead. I think you need to do something similar to Laplace pyramid however in respect to logarithmic scale ... so you have the resolution reduction you need

Comment: Hey @Spektre, thank you for your comment. The mesh index is now calculated by mapping the frequency bin logarithmically. However, in the low frequencies there is a lot of space between the peaks, because bin `x` gets mapped to index `3` and bin `x + 1` gets mapped to index `50` (It's just an exaggeration, but you get the point).
Do I have to interpolate the values in between?

Comment: Yes you do ... for stuff like this is usuall to use laplace pyramid (you might now it as MIPMAPing) so you create half resolution data from your original one then half of the half ... until you got resolution 1.... then whenever you want to pick a value that contains x values together you just chose the closest resolution reduction (mimmap level) and take single value from there  ...

Comment: for 1D data like yours it would be triangle instead of pyramid ...and as the scale used is changing with coordinate you might have more mipmap leveles on one side of data then on the other ....

Comment: I'm really new to graphics programming, so I will have to read up on the stuff you mentioned. But one question I still have is: Doesn't this mess up the analytical part of my graph? You can obviously present data however you want, but when I start to interpolate the level between frequencies I feel like this gives a wrong impression of what's actually going on, no?

Comment: yes and no ... you want to render a lot of info into single pixel so you got two options either select just single frequency (however that will lead to aliasing unless the selection is based on some knowledge of the signal)  or You compute some coumulative info that is displayed as single pixel. What I proposed is averaging but there are also other methods like min,max,median ....

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I'll give it some thought in the following few days and get back to this question. Hopefully to mark it as answered ;)

Comment: You still have no answers here ... as you did not include MCVE nor sample in/out so most people are reluctant to answer ... me included as I usually test stuff by trying to code it first but without data I cant ... because I can not replicate your problem and generating data on my own may lead to very different results ....

Comment: @Spektre I am aware of that. I thought I'm just gonna try and break down my problem to a point where no example is needed. But I'm not sure if I was able to articulate it well enough. I'll try to reproduce my issue in the simplest way possible and add it as a JavaScript snippet.